# Android handler vs service

Tags: android, android-service, background-process, android-handler

I have got na application that have to check a website every minute even if app is closed too. I dont know what should I use do do that. Handler or Service?
Thanks! John

Comment: Use a Service..

Answer (score 2):

Service

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface. Another application component can start a service and it will continue to run in the background even if the user switches to another application. Additionally, a component can bind to a service to interact with it and even perform interprocess communication (IPC). For example, a service might handle network transactions, play music, perform file I/O, or interact with a content provider, all from the background.

Handler:

> A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue.
>
> There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) to schedule messages and runnables to be executed as some point in the future; and (2) to enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.

What you need is a `Service`.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, though Handlers can be useful in this type of use case.

Answer (score 0):

Neither.

> The [Alarm Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running.

Comment: Not really. Try getting `AlarmManager` to start something every minute on most modern phones. Never gonna happen with all the battery-saving optimizations going on.